# Inconsistent state Impala

Tags: amazon-s3, impala, data-corruption

I store the data on AWS S3 which is queried by Impala. I have recently purged underlying S3 directory for the reason of data corruption. Now there is no data in Impala table (select query shows 0 results), however, when I try to truncate the table I get this error message:

```
CatalogException: Failed to truncate table: test_table. Table may be in a partially truncated state. CAUSED BY: FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://dir1/dir2/test_data/test_file_07_07_2019
```

Seems like Impala looks for the file which is already deleted. 
How to resolve this inconsistent state?

Comment: did you try `INVALIDATE METADATA <table_name>` before `TRUNCATE`?

Comment: I did, but the error persists